# How do i run a swf file in another swf file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I got a client with a GUI for my game and i tried adding when you press a button to open another swf file. So basically after when the button is being pressed to be redirected to the other swf file.
Here is the code:

```
override public function set pressed(param1:Boolean) : void
      {
         super.pressed = param1;
         bitmap.y = !!param1 ? Number(1) : Number(0);
      }
```

And i have tried doing this:

```
override public function set pressed(param1:Boolean) : void
      {
         super.pressed = param1;
         bitmap.y = !!param1 ? Number(1) : Number(0);
         mainLoader = new Loader();
         url = new URLRequest("battle/battle.swf");
         mainLoader.load(url);
         addChild(mainLoader);      
}
```

But it just messes up everything in the client and it doesn't even work...

Comment: Please elaborate on explaining "*messes up everything*". The 2nd snippet, as you provided it, should start loading some external SWF while **adding** it to the existing display list hierarchy. If by "*redirecting*" you mean you want to completely remove the current content to run an external SWF, you should do it in a slightly different way.

Comment: i just want it to start loading an external swf and display it

Comment: You did that. It loads an external SWF and displays it. There's no problem here, unless you explain in terms of "*expected vs actual*" results.

Comment: so i expected when the function pressed is activated to display the other swf file and instead of that it showed up the button in another shape like really really small like 4 pixels and when i try to click it , it doesn„t do anything

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I still find your "*expected behavior*" explanations to be exceedingly confusing, but I assume you want your application to show another SWF just like next page in browser.

```
function nextSWF(url:String):void
{
    // Keep the stage reference because it will be lost
    // once everything is detached from the stage,
    // and that is exactly what's about to happen.
    var aStage:Stage = stage;
    var aLoader:Loader = new Loader;
    
    // Remove the current application visuals.
    dismantle(aStage);
    
    // Load the new content.
    aStage.addchild(aLoader);
    aLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
}

// This method recursively destroys the whole display list
// branch, starting from the given display list node.
function dismantle(target:DisplayObjectContainer):void
{
    if (!target) return;
    
    while (target.numChildren)
    {
        // Get a reference to the topmost display child.
        var aChild:DisplayObject = target.getChildAt(target.numChildren - 1);
        
        // Dismantle it as well if it contains things, 
        // then remove it from the display list.
        dismantle(aChild as DisplayObjectContainer);
        target.removeChild(aChild);
    }
}
```

Then, you use it in your script as following:

```
override public function set pressed(param1:Boolean) : void
{
    // The remnants of your script, whatever it is.
    super.pressed = param1;
    bitmap.y = !!param1 ? Number(1) : Number(0);
    
    // Remove the current content and load the next one.
    nextSWF("battle/battle.swf");
}
```